# how to calculate mean of several gray scale images in matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, vectorization

I have a set of images and I want to calculate mean of these images in Matlab and then subtract the mean from all images.Then, plot the distribution of images through hist function in Matlab.

Thanks

Comment: This should be pretty simple - what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose images are in the same size, if you have for example 3 images the following code would do what you what:

```
images       = image1 + image + image3;
meanOfImages = images ./ 3;
image1       = image1 - meanOfImages; 
image2       = image2 - meanOfImages; 
image3       = image3 - meanOfImages;
```

The idea is to sum all the images then divide the resulting matrix element-wise by number of images and that would be the mean of them, then subtract this matrix from each image matrix.

Comment: This is not necessarily a good idea. Many images will come into MATLAB as `uint8` rather than double, and your first step will then saturate the images at 255. Better to perform the division first, and then add - or even better, use the command `imlincomb` from Image processing Toolbox, which handles numerical issues properly and speeds things up by using the Intel PPL.

Comment: They can be casted to `double`.

Comment: @Sameh Kamal, your code calculates the single pixel mean of each pixel, not the mean of all the images. The output of `meanOfImages` in your code is a matrix, not a scalar.  By taking a mean of something, one usually expects a scalar output.

Comment: @natan .. I know what you mean, but in the question, he want a mean matrix not scalar.